# One time text timer for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timer

i have a question about timer functions in javascript.
is there a way to create a simple function that i will call during my game that will last for example only 3 seconds. It will be called only one time but i dont know how to set it to be exactly x-seconds long.  And my other part of this question is how can i delay some function. (For example: I want to call `Boss();` after my text finishes (i want to have it on canvas for a shorter period of time))

Comment: RTLM? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: You don't have a single question mark, or any code.

Comment: @MarcB RTLM? Real-time logistics management? Rotated transmission line matrix?

Comment: @MarcB Radio Télévision Libre des Mille, Real Time Link Management,  Rational Test Lab Management

Comment: as was suggested by others on the site, a more polite version of RTFM. "read the linked manual"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `setTimeout()` function to make the system wait for a specific duration, eg. `setTimeout(afterThreeSecondsDoThis, 3000)`. So what you can do is setup a variable `timer` to keep track of the *timeout* and provide a function that you'd like to execute when the time is up. Check out this fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/V4cPR/

```
var timer = null;
var WAIT_TIME = 3000; // 3 seconds

var afterThreeSecondsDoThis = function () {
    alert('3 seconds has passed!');

    clearTimeout(timer); // remove timer
};
var startTimer = function () {
    timer = setTimeout(afterThreeSecondsDoThis, WAIT_TIME);
};
var boss = function() {
      alert('Now enjoy the show!');  
};

startTimer();

var text = $('#text').animate({
    top: '-1200'
}, 40000, 'linear', function () {
    // text has finished animating
    boss();
});
```

You can learn more about:

- `.setTimeout()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout
- `.clearTimeout()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the first part. What does "last for example only 3 seconds." mean?

For a delay:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //do stuff
}, milliseconds)
```

Comment: That is really helpfull for the 2nd part. What i ment was i want to have floating text in the middle of my canvas for 3 seconds. and thats it...

Comment: @Toesmash We don't ask multiple questions in one post at SO, that's how the questions stay most useful to others